Comparison of Transformation Matrices U with Different Parameters
I want to transform any complex matrix into this U form.
$$U =  
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\\\
   -b^* & a^*
 \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
  cos\theta exp(i\lambda) & sin\theta exp(i\mu) \\\\
   -sin\theta exp(-i\mu) & cos\theta exp(-i\lambda)
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Firstly, I consider this form to represent rotations and scaling/contractions in the complex plane.
$$U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
   -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\\\
   \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
I was able to represent U in two cases when it consists solely of real numbers like the one above.
Fisrt case is
($\theta, \lambda , \mu $) = ($\frac{\pi}{4}, \pi, \pi$)
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  cos\frac{\pi}{4} exp(i\pi) & sin\frac{\pi}{4} exp(i\pi) \\\\
   -sin\frac{\pi}{4} exp(-i\pi) & cos\frac{\pi}{4} exp(-i\pi)
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Second case is ($\theta, \lambda , \mu $) = ($-\frac{3\pi}{4}, 0, 0$)
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  cos(-\frac{3\pi}{4}) & sin(-\frac{3\pi}{4}) \\\\
   -sin(-\frac{3\pi}{4})  & cos(-\frac{3\pi}{4}) 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I'm curious about the difference between these two cases, where both cases yield the same original matrix values, but represent different transformations in the complex plane.
